# Notation for polynomials and equating coefficients

Tags: polynomials, notation

I am reading a paper that defines $P_k(s|t)$ as a polynomial of degree $k$ in $s$ given $t$. Does this mean that each term is of the form $f_{k}(t)s^{k}$? (What does "given $t$" mean?)

The paper says that by equating coefficients in the equation 
$$P_k(s+u|t+u)=P_k(s|t)+P_k(s|u)$$
then $P_k(s|t)$ must be a polynomial in $s$ and $t$ of degree $\leq k+1$ i.e. $P_k(s|t)=P_{k+1}(s,t)$. Why is $P_k(s|t)$ a polynomial $t$?

Comment: Can you name the paper? Without context or an example of what the paper means by this notation, I'm not sure what "given $t$" should mean.

Comment: I was able to figure out eventually what the "given $t$" means and why $P_k(s|t)$ is a polynomial in $s$ and $t$. I posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $P_k(s|t)$ is a polynomial in $s$ for a given $t$,
$$
P_k(s|t)=\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(t)s^i
$$
If 
$$
P_k(s+u|t+u)=P_k(s|t) +P_k(s|u)
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(t+u)\sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j} s^ju^{i-j}=\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(t)s^i +\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(u)s^i
$$
Equating the coefficient on $s^k$ we get
$$
f_k(t+u)= f_k(t) + f_k(u)
$$
Hence $f_k$ is linear and the first term is a polynomial in $s$ and $t$ of degree $\leq k+1$. Equating the coefficients on $s^{k-1}$ we get
$$
kf_k(t+u)u + f_{k-1}(t+u) = f_{k-1}(t)+ f_{k-1}(u)
$$
so $f_{k-1}$ must be quadratic in which case the second term is of degree $\leq k+1$.
Proceeding recursively, $P_k(s|t)$ is a polynomial in $s$ and $t$ of degree $\leq k+1$.